# Error in parsing html content using DOMDocument of PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Can anyone please help me in finding out what have I done wrong in the code given below.

I have a PHP variable named **news_content** whose value is the following html...

```
<p><img src="./images/image1.jpeg" alt=""></p>
```

This value for variable **news_content** is obtained from a database query.

The function below creates a DOMDocument object using the variable  **news_content** :

```
public function convert_to_tinymce_data($news_content)
{
    $dom=new DOMDocument();

    $dom->loadHTML($news_content);

    $img_nodes=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($img_nodes as $link)
    {
        $img_link=$link->getAttribute('src');

        echo $link->getAttribute('src');

    }
}
```

But nothing is being echoed (receiving a blank page).

Comment: Have you activate error reporting? (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script); Probably your HTML string is empty. Otherwise you have to post the HTML. With correct HTML, above script works.

Comment: If I directly assign the html string i.e. $news_content= '<p><img src="./images/image1.jpeg" alt=""></p>'; ,then code works .But when it is fetched from a database(where it is stored as text data type) and then stored in the variable($news_content) , it does not work even though DOMDocument object is getting created(checked it using " echo $dom->saveHTML() ") .                                                                    And yes I have verified that the variable $news_content is not empty.Please any ideas.Thank you

Comment: No. Can you edit post adding HTML from database? (if possible, copy-and-paste directly from phpMyAdmin edit form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tryed this code and it works:

```
$n = '<p><img src="./images/image1.jpeg" alt=""></p>';

function convert_to_tinymce_data($news_content){
 $dom=new DOMDocument();

 $dom->loadHTML($news_content);
 $img_nodes=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

 foreach($img_nodes as $link) {
        $img_link=$link->getAttribute('src');
        echo $img_link;
  }
}

convert_to_tinymce_data($n);
```

I see you have `public function`, but I don't see class. If it's global function, not a method of a class, that's the reason why it doesn't work. Or you don't call function properly.

(What you have there is function definition... it executes after you call it... Having same variable names in your function's definition and outside is bad practice and can be easily turn into problem)

Just to add: Check you're error_log file and let us know is there something interesting in it...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Well the method is inside a class(am using codeigniter).I just didn't show it here.If I directly assign the html string to a variable (like you did) it works ,but when it is fetched from a database(where it is stored as text data type) and then stored in the variable($news_content) it does not work even though DOMDocument object is getting created(checked it using "echo $dom->saveHTML()")

Comment: Do `var_dump($news_content);` after obtaining value from database. See what is different between this and working example and then adjust it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again.Strangely, the code which was not working earlier(and I honestly executed it many times for testing) has suddenly started giving correct output(and I do not know how). And of course I tried your var_dump suggestion too. But somehow the code started working before any modification was needed.But thanks for your amazing support and guidance